# Check box selection by label without xpath Options

Tags: java, css, selenium, webdriver

In our application we have check box under one div, so i cant select
css for any specific check box. We will run the ame test on android
browser as well and dont want to use xpath to locate the elements.
Please help me to find a way to locate the check box by label .

this is the sample code i wrote the first offer from the list using
css class:

List select1 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".offer"));//.offer is css for offer Class
driver.findElement((By) select1.get(0)).click();//want to click on first element

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxWebElement cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.By
    at com.pontiflex.webview.browser.MultiofferPageTests.withoutOffer(MultiofferPageTests.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

the scenario is we have a offer class where we all offer displaying
with different label and checkbob and i have to select any specific
check box. I tried above code gave me following error

Any solution????

Thanks
RP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not do something like this

```
List<WebElement> select1 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='offer'] input[type='checkbox']"));
select1.get(0).click();
```

Comment: you mean List<WebElement> select1? Perhaps that needs to be edited :)

Comment: Thanks you for the catch and I have updated it.  I wasn't too familiar with the Java side of selenium my experience is with C# where it would by called like this List<IWebElement> select = etc...